# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded. While generating jasper report

Tags: oracle, jasper-reports

While generating report through jasper we are getting exception error as ...

```
Error filling print... net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for : risk
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for : risk 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.prepare(JRFillSubreport.java:729) 

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: You can ask your DBA to help identify the cause of a problem. Maybe some application does not close connections or use a large connection pool

Answer (score 0):

Сonnect to the database and check the open_cursors limits:

```
select value from v$parameter  where name='open_cursors'
```

So we list the top 20 sessions which are currently opening most cursors:

```
select * from ( select ss.value, sn.name, ss.sid from v$sesstat ss, v$statname sn where ss.statistic# = sn.statistic# and sn.name like '%opened cursors current%' order by value desc) where rownum < 21;
```

The solution is to increase the no. of the open_cursors parameter as :

```
alter system set open_cursors=400 scope=both
```